# function in controller no load

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers, conflict

I don't know why my function is not load, this code:

```
include_once('Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/AttributeController.php');

class Singsys_ColorSelector_Override_Admin_Catalog_Product_AttributeController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_AttributeController {

public function saveAction() {
    Mage::log('ExampleText:', null, 'mylog.log');
}
}
```

And my config.xml

```
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <Singsys_ColorSelector_Override before="Mage_Adminhtml">Singsys_ColorSelector_Override_Admin</Singsys_ColorSelector_Override>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
```

Any hints, why my saveAction not work? When I write log in Mage class all is ok. I have also conflict in another module, when I write this function in another module function is work. I try switch off conflicts module in admin and in code, but this is not help.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
require_once('Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/Product/AttributeController.php');

class Singsys_ColorSelector_Override_Admin_Catalog_Product_AttributeController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_AttributeController {

public function saveAction() {
    Mage::log('ExampleText:', null, 'mylog.log');
}
}
```

Comment: It does not work for me

Comment: give me path where you create controller file

Comment: try to not use Override folder direct use Adminhtml folder

Answer (score -1):

I find solution, I use 'depends' in the second modules and this is help me.